# Windows Search folder constantly recreated

Tags: windows-7, permissions, search

Today I noticed the Windows Search service wasn't running. I recently rearranged a bunch of disks so I figured it just got confused. I tried to start the service manually but I got Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified.

I searched around and realized this is a fairly common problem. A good summary of fixes is on this page: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/85803-index-windows-search-service.html

The trouble I'm having is on Step 3 on that page. If I go to the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\ folder, it says I don't have access to the Data folder. If I'm quick enough, I can change permissions on the folder and then open it, but it's empty. This is the weird part: If I try to make a new folder, it gets removed before I can even type a name. If I change permissions on the Data folder, they get changed back in a few seconds. If I move a folder into the Data folder, the whole folder gets deleted! A few seconds later it shows up again with the same permissions, empty again.

How do I find out what's messing with my Data folder?

A hint is that I tried deleting the files in C:\windows\system32\config\TxR but some of them are still locked by another program, even though Windows Search isn't running.

Comment: There are programs to unlock a file ( by ending the process that has access to the file ).  Have you tried a program like `Unlocker`?

Comment: `Unlocker` says there are no locks on the file. When I try to delete the file, Explorer says it's open in "System". Sysinternals' `Process Explorer` also says the files are open in System.

Comment: Unlocker should allow you to delete the file, which requires a reboot, the file is then deleted before any services are started.

Comment: That looks useful, but it doesn't fix my Data folder.

Comment: Have you tried and offline boot tool like Microsoft DaRT, to delete the files while windows is offline?